# How can I solve Class pusher does not exist error?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, pusher

I'm trying to build a real-time chat application using Pusher, based on a tutorial found here: https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/chat/chat.html

Locally (Windows) everything seems to be working fine, however when I try to deploy it on a Linux server things don't work so well and I'm receiving the following error:

```
Class pusher does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class pusher does not exist at /home/tgbinfo/public_html/system/applications/erp2/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/tgbinfo/public_html/system/applications/erp2/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(779): ReflectionClass->__construct('pusher')
#1 /home/tgbinfo/public_html/system/applications/erp2/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(658): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('pusher')
#2 /home/tgbinfo/public_html/system/applications/erp2/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(609): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('pusher', Array)
#3 /home/tgbinfo/public_html/system/applications/erp2/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(759): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('pusher', Array)
#4 /home/tgbinfo/public_html/system/applications/erp2/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(237): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('pusher')
#5 /home/tgbinfo/public_html/system/applications/erp2/example/app/Http/Controllers/ChatController.php(23): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('make', Array)
#6 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\ChatController->__construct()
```

Caused by the construct method of the ChatController, specifically the App:make('pusher') line:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->pusher = App::make('pusher');
    $this->user = Session::get('user');
    $this->chatChannel = self::DEFAULT_CHAT_CHANNEL;
}
```

In Javascript things are still fine, I'm still getting the correct messages for connecting to Pusher.

```
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID ####
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"chat-1429-3653"}}
```

I've read around the internet and already tried some of the following things:

- Use chmod 777 on the bootstrap/cache folder.
- Composer dump-autoload
- Clear artisan cache and configs
- Reinstalled pusher using composer
- Checked for differences in the .env-file locally and on the server, they are identical
- Added 'Pusher' => Pusher\Pusher::class, to aliases in app.php

Relevant .env-code:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```

Composer.json:

```
    "pusher/pusher-http-laravel": "^4.2",
```

broadcasting.php:

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env( 'PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER' ),
            'encrypted' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Any idea on how I can solve this error?

Comment: Please confirm the php version on server... also `composer update` could help.

Comment: Make sure you have not uploaded the `vendor`foler on server.

Comment: PHP Version on the server is 7.1.3, locally it's 7.1.1 but I'm not sure if that would cause issues. composer update gives the message _nothing to install or update_. The vendor folder is not uploaded but was generated by composer.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `config/app.php`? I have done so but this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have not updated dependency on server. Use "composer install" command to install all dependency. Then user "composer dump-autoload" to reload all dependency.

Comment: Composer install gives the message _nothing to install or update_. I have also tried to remove the entire contents of the vendor-folder and making composer reinstall everything. However this problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own issue, it seems like the `packages.php` and `services.php`-files in `bootstrap/cache` were not being updated, even after running multiple `artisan cache:clear` and `artistan config:cache` commands. In the end I removed both files and ran `artisan cache:clear` again. The newly generated files contained the pusher-information Laravel needed.